# I don't want to be the one that "have" or "has"?

Tags: verb-agreement, relative-clauses, conjugation, have

Which one of these sentences is correct?

1. I don't want to be the one that **have** to explain to your parents why you are not going to graduate.
2. I don't want to be the one that **has** to explain to your parents why you are not going to graduate.

Comment: *Have* is possible here because there is a wish (want) being expressed. This is the subjunctive mood, but I think it is pretty rare these days and probably only exists in a few dialects. You could always use *will have to*.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence has a relative clause, introduced by 'that', and the embedded clause obeys the rules of subject agreement.  Since the subject of the relative clause is 'the one', which is singular, you should use 'has' to agree with it, not 'have'.

(Phil's comment about subjunctive is not a part of modern English.)

Comment: +1 use *has*, always, in this context. And that's the first time I've written *always* on this site.

Comment: But, to be clear, "We don't want to be the ones that have to explain ..."; 'have' goes with plural subjects.